# Unable to Maintain Multiple session in axis 1.4

Tags: error-handling, axis, netsuite

I want to add, get and update customer details from Netsuite. I have used apache axis 1.4 (recommended by Netsuite) to communicate web services exposed by Netsuite. I can be logged in successfully, however once I log in, I am unable to do further operations like add, update and get customers.

Here is the error msg I got:

```
AxisFault

faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode: 
faultString: Your connection has timed out.  Please log in again.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: For other people stuck with the same issue here is where is the problem. Apparently NetSuite has changed their web services url without updating their documentation. The new url you have to use is:

https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/services/...

I suspect this is an end point for North America -based customers.

Big Thanks! to Paul Hooker for his invaluable **[tip](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/NetSuite-SuiteTalk-Web-Services-stopped-3295906.S.198688554)**.